# HTACCESS rewrite URL on 404 error

Tags: .htaccess

In htaccess file, I currently redirect user when a 404 error occurs

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?p=error
```

However, **in addition to this redirection**, I want the URL in the address bar to become www.mywebsite.com

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: full content of my htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?p=error
```

Comment: Do you have multiple domains on the same root ? by default the above would become `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?p=error` or are u saying u want to internally redirect the error so it doesn't show the `index...` on the URL.

Comment: @Prix Indeed I have, good sir.

Comment: @Prix The reason for my request is that my links are in this format "?page=somepage&..." so if the user requested an inexisting page, the variables will keep on appending to that wrong link (so he will continuously have a 404 error)

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess` it might be more complicated then it look likes depend on the rules you already have there for your site itself.

Comment: So you want the 404 page to be located at `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?p=error` but you want it to appear in the address bar as `http://www.mywebsite.com`?

Comment: @UserIsCorrupt from what I understood, he wants the error to be per domain, right now domainA is the primary so any error goes to `domainA.com/index.php?p=error` as it is but rather he wants a per domain error.

Comment: The htaccess file is only for the domain specified here, it is not in the main root of the server.

Comment: @Prix see edit in main post

Comment: @AdamStrudwick if u have per domain htaccess then you can use `ErrorDocument 404 http://thisdomain.com/index.php?p=error` or `ErrorDocument 404 http://thatdomain.com/index.php?p=error` instead of just `/index...`

Comment: Problem is: the page shown is index.php?p=error, but in the address bar, there is still the wrong page (ex: mydomain.com/thewrongpage)

Comment: I think this is a case of framing the problem wrong: the problem is not that your 404 page has the "wrong" URL, it is that links on that 404 page point to invalid locations. That is a problem with how the 404 page is rendered, not what URL it appears under - i.e. you need to change your PHP, not your `.htaccess`

Comment: Also, `ErrorDocument` does not "redirect the user" - it tells *the server* (Apache) what output to show the user when a 404 is generated. This is quite important, as things like search engine "spiders" will act in a different way when seeing a 404 than if they are told to load a different page.

Comment: @IMSoP I don't really see how I could change my PHP except by adding "index" before my links ("?p=..."). But is there any way to achieve this using solely htaccess?

Comment: @AdamStrudwick Well, yes, you would have to make them normal links relative to the root of the site (e.g. `/index.php?p=foo`); using links all starting with `?` is an unusual way of building site navigation - do you have a reason for it? If your problem is that you want anything not on `index.php` to be automatically re-directed to `index.php` (since only the query string ever varies), then that too is a different problem to what you have described.

Comment: @IMSoP thanks, I'll think about it... might go for changing the links, as it is way easier than playing with htaccess (which I don't master very well)